# how to get current page size (that is raw content) in mediawiki api?

Tags: api, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I don't know where to put the size argument, here I only managed to get a single edit size:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=size&format=xml&titles=United_States_of_America`

but I need the size of whole raw content as it is on last revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that, the page *United States of America* contains the following 69 bytes:

```
#REDIRECT [[United States]]

{{Redr|move|from long name|printworthy}}
```

What this code means is that it's a redirect and the name of the real article is *United States*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=size&format=xml&titles=United_States

This returns the size you want: 267582 bytes.

Another option would be let the API follow the redirect automatically using `redirects`:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=size&format=xml&titles=United_States_of_America&redirects

Answer (score 2):

[`rvsize`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#revisions_.2F_rv) does lead to the output of the size of the *whole* revison.

In your example the size is really only 69 bytes, as you can see when you [also read the content](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=size|content&format=xml&titles=United_States_of_America):

```
REDIRECT [[United States]]

{{Redr|move|from long name|printworthy}}
```

To automatically follow such redirects, use the `redirects` parameter for [resolving redirects](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Resolving_redirects) - in your case [`prop=revisions&rvprop=size&titles=United_States_of_America&redirects`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=size&format=xml&titles=United_States_of_America&redirect)s which outputs a size of currently 267582 bytes.